# Is it possible to specify the beginning and end points of the file to be opened before opening?

Tags: emeditor

Is it possible to specify the beginning and end points of the file to be opened *before* opening? For example, if I have a file of size 1234567890 bytes and I want to open it from 2345777 to 2345888, how do I set these values *before* opening it, so that the program will not even try to display any data that lays outside of this range?

I do not know how EmEditor reads a file, but the program is able to display a specific fragment (from point X to point Y), and the problem is that I do not see how to set these two values *before* opening. If the point X is equal to the size, the program would display the last byte only.  If the point X is larger than the size, the program would send the corresponding message and not display any data from the file. Otherwise, if the point Y is larger than the size, the program would display the file from point X to the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the beginning and end points of the file in the **File** page of the **Customize** dialog box - **From** and **To** text boxes. This will change global settings, and so you will need to reset these settings before you open another file normally.

[image: EmEditor - Customize - File]